# How can I run a Node 6 npm package in a Node 5.6.0 environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6

I'm currently using a package for running cross browser javascript tests called `easy-sauce`. In short, my `package.json` file calls that for the `test` command:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "easy-sauce"
  }
}
```

When I'm using a Node 6 environment, and run `npm test`, all is well. However, the project I'm using it with still needs Node 5.6.0. When I run `npm test` in this environment, I see the following error:

```
/data/projects/easytest/node_modules/easy-sauce/lib/cli.js:114
function formatResult(result = {}) {
                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/data/projects/easytest/node_modules/easy-sauce/bin/easy-sauce:6:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

Is there a way to get this working within the Node 5.6.0 environment?

Comment: Have you considered using the node version manager to run 5.6 for this project? You could toggle back and forth if you wanted.

Comment: I already do use nvm when switching between projects, but this particular project that needs easy-sauce also needs to run on 5.6. Easy sauce doesn't seem to want to run in that environment and only seems to work in 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error isn't related to the easy-sauce package, it has to do with your version of node.

According to node.green, default parameters were added in version 6.2.2

http://node.green/

Unfortunately you wont be able to run the code in node 5. Default parameters are in node 6.2, hence that error.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "check the old fashioned way" or use babel. The use of default parameters is within the easy-sauce code, not mine. Can you elaborate?

Comment: ohh, I thought you had written that.  Unfortunately you wont be able to run the code in node 5. Default parameters are in node 6.2, hence that error.

Comment: If you want to edit your answer to reflect that it's not possible, I can mark your answer as correct. Thanks Jordan.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
Upgrade your version of node/npm.  This is not always possible, depending on deployment environment.

**Option 2**
You need to use a transpiler (e.g. Babel) to convert the ES6 code to ES5 and reference the built script.  This solution is the one you always have the power to do.

**Option 3**
Fork/update `easy-sauce` to include a transpiler to build an ES5 version (in the `dist` folder is a common destination).  The package.json of the package can be directed to this location.